# check if php "get" isset by having a whitelist array

Tags: php

I made an own frontcontroller where I get the requested URL. With it I'm handling change sites etc.

If on sites I'm using get I have a whitelist, which checks the allowed get names, else site is running into 404. For example:

```
if(isset($_GET['up']) || isset($_GET['product']) || isset($_GET['del'])  isset($_GET['order'])){
...
}
```

But now I would made an array like that:

```
$getwhitelist = array(
  "product",
  "del",
  "up",
  "order"    
);
```

and check if one of these names in array is set. How I could do that?

I tried with foreach:

```
foreach ($getwhitelist as $getwhitelistvalue){
    if(isset($GET[$getwhitelistvalue])){
        ...
    }
}
```

But no success.

Comment: i guess you misplled the $_GET to $GET

Comment: $_GET is your friend :)

Comment: FYI, that is not actually a whitelist ... You are checking if all of the parameters your script expects are set. A whitelist would rather be checking if _only_ parameters with pre-defined names were passed, and throw an error otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the _ in get

```
foreach ($getwhitelist as $getwhitelistvalue){
    if(isset($_GET[$getwhitelistvalue])){
        ...
    }
}
```